# Getting 422 Unprocessable Entity while submitting Form with ajax in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm submitting my form using ajax in laravel

> Output:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"name":["The name field is required."],"image":["The image field is required."]}}
```

> View:

```
{{  Form::open(array('route' => 'ajax-add-record','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data','files'=> true,'class'=>'add','id'=>'frmadd')) }}   

        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                         <h2 class="card-inside-title">Name</h2>
                                        <div class="form-line focused">
                                    {{ Form::text('name','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name','id'=>'name']) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                         <h2 class="card-inside-title">Image</h2>
                                        <div class="form-line focused">
                                        {{ Form::file('image',['class'=>'form-control']) }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
    <button class="btn btn-info add_button btn-xs p-3 hide" type="button"><i class="material-icons">add</i> Add</button>
    </div>

 {{ Form::close()}}
```

> Script:

```
$('#frmadd').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });
        $.ajax({    
          url: APP_URL+'/add',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(response)
          {

          },
          error: function(data)
          {
     
          }
          });
});
```

Comment: You submitted without input data?

Comment: @STA: required is not issue but why i'm getting : The given data was invalid and in console also it is showing error : 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Comment: 422 unprocessable entity is the http status and message laravel returns upon failed validation.